# How to compare number in list with float in python

Tags: python, xlwings

import xlwings as xw

@xw.func
def double_sum(x,y,z):
    """Returns twice the sum of the two arguments"""
    wb=xw.Book.caller()
    a=y/z
    if  x=='Interior Panels':
        sht=wb.sheets[0].range('M17:T17').expand().value 
    elif x=='One short edge discontinuous':
        sht=wb.sheets[0].range('M18:T18').expand().value 
    elif x=='One long edge discontinuous':
        sht=wb.sheets[0].range('M19:T19').expand().value 
    elif x=='Two adjacent edges discontinuous':
        sht=wb.sheets[0].range('M20:T20').expand().value 
    elif x=='Two short edges discontinuous':
        sht=wb.sheets[0].range('M21:T21').expand().value 
    elif x=='Two long edge discontinuous':
        sht=wb.sheets[0].range('M22:T22').expand().value 
    elif x=='Three edges discontinuous(One long edge continuous)':
        sht=wb.sheets[0].range('M23:T23').expand().value 
    elif x=='Three edges discontinuous(One short edge continuous)':
        sht=wb.sheets[0].range('M24:T24').expand().value 
    elif x=='Four edges discontinuous':
        sht=wb.sheets[0].range('M25:T25').expand().value 
    for data in sht:
        if data

Here `data` always falls between 1 to 5 but the error is shown on `data<=a` conditional check.
How can i compare my list data in a[] with float x?

Comment: Could you give a couple examples of input and expected output? What should it return with `x=2.2`, `x=7.8`, etc?

Comment: What error are you talking about? Can you show the full traceback? The only error I can see so far is if I use a number like `0` (or anything `< 1`) and that raises `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'outcome' referenced before assignment` because `outcome` is only defined inside that if statement (which doesn't run in those cases).

Comment: if input is 2.2 then outcome should be 2(number in list), if input is 4.5 then outcome should be 4 (number in list). im trying to compare each number one by one so that i can get number just less than provided input, from the list items

Comment: what about input as `0`? what about input as `987`?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather by what you've provided, there are only a couple of errors that can occur in this code.

1. In the case that there is no `data <= x`, your code can fail when it tries return the variable `outcome` without it having been initialized.
2. It looks like you may have bad indentation on the line where you said the error is shown.
3. Your code can fail when `x` is not comparable to the type stored in your list.